# I am not able to get response in angular js $http.post

Tags: php, angularjs

I want to check whether the email id already exists in the db. If the email id exists, it should return false, else true. I'm not able to get the response. I've attached the controller code and the php code. [the variable validUser is undefined]

Controller.js

```
signUpApp.controller("signUpCtrl",function($scope,$http){
        $scope.register = function(form,user){
           if (form.$valid)
           {
             $http.post("http://localhost/checkUser.php?email="+user.email)
                  .then(function(response){
                      validUser=response;
                  });
             if(validUser=="true")
             {
               alert("valid user");
             }
             else
             {
               alert("already exists");
             }

           }
        }
     });
```

checkUser.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "user_details");
//$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
//$email = mysql_real_escape_string($data->email);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$result = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) as count from user where email='$email'");

$outp = "";
$rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)

    if ($rs['count']==0)
    {
        $outp ="true";
    }
    else
    {
        $outp ="false";
    }
$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking the response in the correct place, or rather - at the correct time.

`$http.post` returns immediately. Your `.then` callback is called when the response is returned from the server. The code after the call to `post` (your `if` statements) is executed right after `$http.post` returns, and before the response is received from the server.

You should place your validation code inside your callback:

```
$http.post(...).then(function(response) {
    validUser = response;
    if(validUser==="true") { 
         ...
    } else if (validUser==="false") {
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added the if and else part inside the call back function.Still its not working.

Comment: Time to debug - make sure validUser contains what you think it contains.

Comment: It is working now.I've used response instead of response.data.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You're `if` statement needs to be inside the .then callback, otherwise you'll end up checking it before youre ajax request gets responded to

```
    signUpApp.controller("signUpCtrl",function($scope,$http){
    $scope.register = function(form,user){
       if (form.$valid)
       {
         $http.post("http://localhost/checkUser.php?email="+user.email)
              .then(function(response){
                  validUser=response;
                  if(validUser=="true")
                  {
                    alert("valid user");
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    alert("already exists");
                  }
              });
       }
    }
 });
```